# Istio to allow all egress traffic

Tags: kubernetes, istio, outbound

How do you allow all outbound traffic with Istio?

I tried the following:

- Disable the egress gateway and
  bypass the sidecar with  --set global.proxy.includeIPRanges="0.0.0.0/0\,0.0.0.0/0"

None of the options work, worth to mention I'm using kubernetes 1.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you followed [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#calling-external-services-directly), that's pretty much the way to do it.

Make sure that you update the `istio-sidecar-injector` `ConfigMap` on your namespace and restart your pods.

Comment: Hi the documentation is correct, i noticed that when i define--set global.proxy.includeIPRanges="0.0.0.0/0\,0.0.0.0/0" it doesnt work i also tried --set global.proxy.includeIPRanges="0.0.0.0/0" which is not working either, so i finally tried --set global.proxy.includeIPRanges="0.0.0.0" excluding the netmask and it seemed to be working fine

Comment: @user399256 can/how can I add `global.proxy.includeIPRanges="0.0.0.0" ` in configmaps file ? I tried using `kubectl -n istio-system edit ...` but not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Doing **global.proxy.includeIPRanges: "0.0.0.0" ** won't work. Its probably by defualt 0.0.0.0. 
The global.proxy.includeIPRanges tells istio what IPs are included in the mesh and you want the opposite.

So if your k8s svc CIDR is 10.244.0.0/16 do **global.proxy.includeIPRanges: "10.244.0.0/16"** everything out of that range will bypass istio

Answer (score -1):

@user399256 if you are using helm charts you just edit that under values.yaml 
than you have to implement the change as explained in: [this](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#calling-external-services-directly)
actually did anyone try to allow all traffic using global.proxy.includeIPRanges: "0.0.0.0" ? did it work? is there maybe more elegant way ?

Comment: This should be a comment instead