# ISTIO allow all outbound traffic to a DOMAIN

Tags: openshift, istio, envoyproxy

Similiar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682911/istio-to-allow-all-egress-traffic) topic I need to allow all traffic NOT to IP, but to a domain.
The domain I want to access is google API https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can allow traffic to a specific URL like `www.google.com`, or to a domain like `*.google.com`. See [this task](https://preliminary.istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/#controlled-access-to-external-services).

You can allow traffic to a specific path as well, see [this blog post](https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-monitoring-access-control/).

Comment: This doesn't work - apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: '2019-03-12T13:32:03Z'
  generation: 1
  name: google
  namespace: project
  resourceVersion: '177749718'
  selfLink: >-
    /apis/networking.istio.io/v1alpha3/namespaces/project/serviceentries/google
  uid: 38ca7916-44cb-11e9-aabf-728690ae6e7f
spec:
  hosts:
    - "www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify"
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
  ports:
    - name: https
      number: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS

Comment: So you need to allow access to a specific path only, like "/recaptcha/api/siteverfiy"?

Comment: Well, in this case - yes. Isn't that possible? Also is just making the service entry enough, without any selectors?

Comment: I followed this  guide https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/

Comment: Service Entry does not cover URL paths. To control URL paths, see this blog post - https://preliminary.istio.io/blog/2018/egress-monitoring-access-control/.

Answer (score 0):

Right, I did it with making Service Entry and Virtual entry to google.com.
Not to specific endpoint. Thank you for the help.